# Problem with creating my controller bean, when importing a data from the database

Tags: java, javabeans, jparepository

I have this java class which is importing data from the database:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CashFlowTrainingData {

    private String id;

    @Id
    public String getId() {
        return String.format("{%s:%s:%s:%s}", recordDate, senderPostOfficeCode, quantity, sum);
    }

    @Column(name = "RECORD_DATE")
    private LocalDate date;

    @Column(name = "SENDER_POSTOFFICECODE")
    private String senderPostOfficeCode;

    @Column(name = "QUANTITY")
    private Integer quantity;

    @Column(name = "SUM")
    private Double sum;
}
```

Controller like this, which is post mapping to "PostMan":

```
import (defalt path).CashFlowDataCsvConvertorService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class StartCashFlowProcessController {
    private final CashFlowDataCsvConvertorService cashFlowDataCsvConvertorService;

    public StartCashFlowProcessController(CashFlowDataCsvConvertorService cashFlowDataCsvConvertorService) {
        this.cashFlowDataCsvConvertorService = cashFlowDataCsvConvertorService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/favouriteMainProcess")
    public void start(){
        cashFlowDataCsvConvertorService.mainProcess();
    }
}
```

And client configuration file, in  which there is a

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Configuration
public class ClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

And have an error like this:

```
Error creating bean with name 'startCashFlowProcessController' defined in file [(default path)\controller\StartCashFlowProcessController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'cashFlowDataCsvConvertorService' defined in file [(default path)\service\CashFlowDataCsvConvertorService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'cashFlowTrainingDataRepository' defined in (default path).repositories.CashFlowTrainingDataRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class (default path).models.CashFlowTrainingData
```

I had a problem with a importing data from the database before (helped that I changed jakarta package to javax) and after this have problem with creating these beans. I don't know why it happens( Help me a little, I am a newbie in this...